# Central limit theorem in L^p

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X = X(t)$, $t \in [0,1]$, be a stochastic process such that
$\int_0^1 |X(t)|^p dt < \infty$ almost surely, where $1 \leq p < \infty$.
Thus $X$ takes values in $L^p = L^p([0,1], dt)$. Assume in addition (for simplicity)
that $E(X(t)) = 0$ for every $t$.
Let now $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence
of independent copies of $X$. Under which assumption on the law of $X$ is there
a central limit theorem, that is the sequence
$\frac {1}{\sqrt n} (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$ is tight in $L^p$ and converges towards
some Gaussian process (in $L^p$)? Are there necessary and sufficient conditions
on the law of $X$?

Comment: I'm irritated. Does there exist any non trivial (support in finite dimensional subspace) Gaussian measure on $L^p$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka : E.g., let $X:=\sum_{j=1}^\infty G_jx_j$, where the $G_j$'s are iid standard normal random variables and the $x_j$'s are linearly independent vectors in $L^p$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \|x_j\|_p<\infty$. Then (say, by Kolmogorov's three-series theorem) $X$ will be a Gaussian random vector in $L^p$ with an infinite-dimensional support.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following are necessary and sufficient conditions for the central limit theorem you want:

(i) for $p\in[1,2]$: $$\int_0^1(EX(t)^2)^{p/2}\,dt<\infty\tag{1}$$
(see e.g. [Giné, p. 147](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2045129?seq=1));

(ii) for $p\in(2,\infty)$: (1) & $u^2P(\|X\|>u)\to0$ as $u\to\infty$ (see e.g. [Pisier and Zinn](https://link-springer-com.services.lib.mtu.edu/article/10.1007/BF00533600)).